# Magento2 - How to override this file Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Options.php

Tags: magento2

How to override this file in Magento2

```
Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Options
```

This code is in my `di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Options" type="Magentoo\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Option" />
</config>
```

Comment: A plugin is the best way to change Magento core functionality only public methods can be modified

Comment: how can i create it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with following code in your **di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Option" type="Magentoo\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Option" />
</config>
```

Comment: it not show changes

Comment: give me a proper way to override this file

Comment: its 'Option' not 'Options', check in your code

Answer (score 0):

Create `etc/frontend/di.xml`

```
<type name="\Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Options">
        <plugin name="Custom_Module::aftershowSingle"
                type="Custom\Module\Plugin\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Options"
                sortOrder="10" />
</type>
```

Then create a plugin in your custom module and override path in your module and implement code as your functionality

```
<?php
/**
namespace Custom\Module\Plugin\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle;

class Option
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_registry;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    ) {
        $this->_registry = $registry;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param array $result
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function aftershowSingle(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection,
        $result
    ) {
        if ($this->_registry->registry('mp_flat_catalog_flag')) {
            $result = 0;
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

I just override showsingle method.

**Note**

• Plugins only work on public methods.

• They do not work on final methods, final classes.

• They must be configured in di.xml.

**Important**: plugins can be used on interfaces, abstract classes or parent classes. The plugin methods will be called for any implementation of those abstractions.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way. You can copy that file and paste in `Vendor\YourModuleName\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Options` folder.

Just change whatever you need to change in that file. remove the functions whichever you are not using. run the M2 commands and check the changes.

Create di.xml file with below content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Options" type="Vendor\YourModuleName\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Options"/>
</config>
```