# I have override the block Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Option but is not working

Tags: magento2, preference, magento2bundleproduct

I have followed this [Magento2 - How to override this file Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Options.php](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/304479/magento2-how-to-override-this-file-magento-bundle-block-catalog-product-view-t)  but its now working.